# Using IMAP functions with PHP adds extra attributes to tags

Tags: php, cakephp, imap, cakephp-2.3

So Im using the various IMAP functions for the first time.

Im amused at what I can do with it so far. However, a small issue that I keep seeing is, it likes to add several attributes to my html tag, and a few attributes to my body tag.

`<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">`

`<body lang="EN-US" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72">`

Why does this happen, and any insight towards a method to use to fix this would be awesome!

By The Way: If it helps anyone's answer, I am using CakePHP. So if they have something that would be better to use anyways, I would like to know. I know about their `CakeEmail` class, but I dont fully understand how to use it (yet), aside from sending an email.

Also: (Slightly off topic, and no big deal if theres no help for this)
Would be cool to see if anyone has a few tutorials for some better implementations for IMAP. Anything from basic 'read a few emails in a custom format' to 'a full blown DIY web-based email client'.

I have been using PHP's manuals and a few tutorials found online, but IMAP seems to be a harder topic to find.

EDIT: It only happens when I use `imap_fetchbody()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Well, since its been 6 hours. I guess no one has a clue.
However, I continued to look into the situation.

The problem was the actual content from `imap_fetchbody`. Some emails were including a full html page for the message. For some reason, this HTML was being added into the REST of the legit HTML. Perhaps it was just Chrome, or maybe its the way it works. Not sure. Didn't care enough to continue to look into it.

Regardless, the solution was just to strip certain tags. Even though that's not ENTIRELY what I'm doing, it is the base, and it will hopefully get someone else who has the same question an idea of what they need to do.

If anyone cares, I can elaborate on what I'm doing, with examples. But I'm not trying to spoil anyone's problem solving skills. I know some people don't want a solution just handed to them. ;-)